# How to document possible configuration properties in function argument in JSDOC?

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

How can I document possible configuration properties in function argument in JSDOC:

```
/**
 * N level expectimax AI.
 *
 * @param {object} cfg  config
 *   cfg.minimaxDepth  - limit for minimax search
 *   cfg.expectiDepth  - limit for expectimax search
 *   cfg.weightFn  - position weight function
 *
 * @constructor
 */
function expectimaxAI(brdEngine, cfg) { ... }
```

Which markup is to use for `cfg.minimaxDepth` (`cfg.*`) parameters?

Is it possible to document synthetic `aiCfg` type and put reference to it as:

```
 * @param {aiCfg} cfg  config
```

or somehow else?

Answer (score 1):

After reading [official JSDoc 2.x docs](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/w/list) I make some hack:

```
/**
 * @name BlindWeightRandomCfg
 * @function
 * @param {number} left   weight
 * @param {number} right  weight
 * @param {number} up     weight
 * @param {number} down   weight
 */
```

and refer to non-existing function as:

```
/**
 * Blind weight random AI.
 *
 * @param {Board} brdEngine  board engine from board.js
 * @param {BlindWeightRandomCfg} cfg  configuration settings
 * @constructor
 */
 ai.BlindWeightRandom = function(brdEngine, cfg) { ... }
```

Now argument `cfg` - clickable to definition of `BlindWeightRandomCfg`!

**UPDATE** Another possibility for JSDoc 2.x:

```
/**
 * @name BlindWeightRandomCfg
 * @namespace
 * @property {number} left   weight
 * @property {number} right  weight
 * @property {number} up     weight
 * @property {number} down   weight
 */
```

and for JSDoc 3.x:

```
/**
  @typedef PropertiesHash
  @type {object}
  @property {string} id - an ID.
  @property {string} name - your name.
  @property {number} age - your age.
 */

/** @type {PropertiesHash} */
var props;
```

Seems that `@typedef` is a solution. Please [see other variants](http://justjson.blogspot.com/2013/07/jsdoc-documenting-configparamcustom.html) and [at official docs](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html).